# Cant write to Database Firebase

Tags: android, firebase

```
mDatabse = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");

HashMap<String, String> usermMap = new HashMap<>();
usermMap.put("name", display_name);
usermMap.put("status", "Hey, ich benutze die App.");
usermMap.put("image", "default_pic");
usermMap.put("thumb_image", "default_pic");

mDatabse.setValue(usermMap);
```

Its register only this Accounts but do not Create Database Data.

```html
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "de.epix_crew.epixchat"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    //implementation 'com.android.support:design-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:15.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'


}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

here is this file hope you can help me to get it working. 
Maybe if you have Teamviewer you can see the Problem :)

Thanks too :)

Comment: Did u check permissions? Please explain your problem !

Comment: I Follow a Tutorial on Youtube and now he dont write my Data to Database.

Comment: Here is this Code: https://pastebin.com/5GZtT7xF

Comment: If not working even after setting permissions,Is the code execution getting inside    if (task.isSuccessful())

Comment: what did you mean? sorry my english is not as well ^^

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I extracted the least necessary stuff needed for firebase from your code and tried it. It worked with my test database. 
Here's the code I used:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DatabaseReference mDatabse;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private Button mCreateBtn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        mCreateBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
        mCreateBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String display_name = "Otto";
                String email = "mmuuuu@email.com";
                String password = "111111";

                if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(display_name) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(email) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
                    register_user(display_name, email, password);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void register_user(final String display_name, String email, String password) {
        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                    FirebaseUser current_user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                    String uid = current_user.getUid();

                    mDatabse = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");

                    HashMap<String, String> usermMap = new HashMap<>();
                    usermMap.put("name", display_name);
                    usermMap.put("status", "Hey, ich benutze die - App.");
                    usermMap.put("image", "default_pic");
                    usermMap.put("thumb_image", "default_pic");

                    mDatabse.setValue(usermMap);

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Fehler! Überbrüfe noch einmal die Eingabefelder!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

(Notice, that I didn't use EditText fields, but put values directly in the String variables, for simplification.)

Here are my database rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

And here is the written data from my database. (I exported it to a JSON-file):

```
"Users" : {
  "image" : "default_pic",
  "name" : "Otto",
  "status" : "Hey, ich benutze die - App.",
  "thumb_image" : "default_pic"
},
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your linked code. You should put the code into your question, so that everybody can see it directly.

Comment: Can you post ur Rules for DB and your implementation you use?

Comment: Yes, after dinner ;)

Comment: Okey Thank you :)

Comment: you finished your dinner? :D he dont put data in database xD where is my Problem xDD Maybe Teamviewer Meeting ? ^^

Comment: hmm have this same but he dont put in my database? maybe its FireStore ? I have connect it too? i dont know.. its possible to disable Firestore ???

Comment: No, I also connected to Firestore. It still works. Have you activated the authentication method email-adress/password in your Firebase console?

Comment: Yes i have ... he crates The Account under autantification but Database still be empty. See always please weit... and do not  skip u implemention are 15.0.0 ?

Comment: Yeah, 15.0.0 is correct. This is really odd. Can you post your build.gradle file? maybe there is something wrong

Comment: Okey i have added the Code on top :)

Comment: Laut dein Profil kannst du auch deutsch wäre das nicht besser ^^ so verstehe ich auch bisschen was ^^

Comment: Das wird hier nicht gern gesehen, aber ich mach mal ne Ausnahme: Also, ich hab deinen ursprünglichen Code nochmal ausprobiert, also mit EditText, Progressbar und allem. Der funktioniert einwandfrei. Der Account wird angelegt und die Daten in die DB geschrieben. Das einzige Problem ist, dass die Progressbar nicht verschwindet, weil du `mRegProgress.dismiss();` auskommentiert hast. Die einzige Vermutung, die ich jetzt noch habe ist, dass du beim Anlegen des Accounts eine email-Adresse verwendest, die schon existiert. In dem Fall wird es nicht funktionieren. Nimm also immer _frische_ Daten

Comment: Sorrry for the German. Here the translation: I tried your original code again, with EditText, ProgressBar and stuff, and it works perfectly. The account is created and the data is written to the DB. The only problem is, that the progressbar does not disappear, because you commented `mRegProgress.dismiss();` out. The only idea, that I have now is, that you try to create an account with an email address, that already exists. In this case, it won't work. So, always take _fresh_ data

Comment: Wäre es mal möglich das du bei mir kurz per TV schauen kannst? Wäre echt nett. Ich habe immer frische Daten.

Comment: Its ok to check my Problem on TV? After we Found the Problem i can post here the result.

Comment: Ok. schick mir deine daten auf marcel.schoob@live.de

Answer (score 0):

```
if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                FirebaseUser current_user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                String uid = current_user.getUid();

                Log.d("Inside if task successful",".......");
                // added a log to check if excecution gets inside the if block
                mDatabse = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(uid);

                HashMap<String, String> usermMap = new HashMap<>();
                usermMap.put("name", display_name);
                usermMap.put("status", "Hey, ich benutze die - App.");
                usermMap.put("image", "default_pic");
                usermMap.put("thumb_image", "default_pic");

                mDatabse.setValue(usermMap);



                /*
                mRegProgress.dismiss();

                Intent mainIntent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                mainIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                startActivity(mainIntent);
                finish();

                */

            } else {
                mRegProgress.hide();
                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Fehler! Überbrüfe noch einmal die Eingabefelder!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
```

Added a log inside the if block.

Comment: Now Only hes Looping always... i see only :  mRegProgress.setTitle("User Registrierung");
                    mRegProgress.setMessage("Bitte warten... Es kann bis zu 30 Sekunden dauern bis dein Account angelegt wird. Schließe nicht die APP! ");  

in a Loop he dont skip